# SQLiteOpenHelper doesn't update database while changing the DB version

Tags: android, sql, database, sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

I have an issues regarding the SQLiteOpenHelper.
I've created a singleton to acces the Database. In the constructor I call the super method (of SQLiteOpenHelper) with the DATABASE_VERSION, so if I increase the DATABASE_VERSION the onUpgrade should be called right?
But the onUpgrade is never called. 
Is there another property to change to upgrade the DB or something?

Thanks already!

Code sample:

```
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 101;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "dbName.db";

private static final String SQL_CREATE_TESTDB_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE TESTTABLE (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name TEXT)";
private static final String SQL_DELETE_TESTDB_TABLE = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TESTTABLE";    


//Singleton
private static TestDatabase testDatabase = null;

public static TestDatabase getTestDatabase(Context context){
    if(testDatabase == null){
        testDatabase = new TestDatabase(context);
    }
    return testDatabase;
}

//Constructor
private TestDatabase(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

    this.getWritableDatabase(); //DB should upgrade?
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL(SQL_DELETE_TESTDB_TABLE);
    this.onCreate(db);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    //create table
    db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_TESTDB_TABLE);
}
```

//Main activity code part:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    TestDatabase.getTestDatabase(this.getApplicationContext());
```

Comment: PUT your onUpgrade method

Comment: @Xenolion I've added both

Comment: Can you provide what `SQL_DELETE_TESTDB_TABLE` and `SQL_DELETE_TESTDB_TABLE` resolve to. Could possibly be due to their values.

Comment: @MikeT both are added

Comment: trying to run my own version with logging can say that constructor is getting invoked but doesn then go on to onCreate. Stepping through with debug now to see if I can find out what's happening.

Comment: Weird it now appears to be working. try putting breakpoint on this.getWriteableDatabse(); and debug. When it gets to breakpoint. click on Step Into (F7). I f prompted to accept agreements, accept. if prompted to down load download, stop debug and restart debug.

Answer (score 1):

On your TestDatabase class ( The class that extends SQLiteOpenHelper), you need to override onUpgrade method. I believe you already have onCreate method . Sample would be ,

```
  public TestDatabase (Context context) {
    super(context,DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

 @Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(<YOUR QUERIES TO EXECUTE WHEN APPLICATION IS FIRST INSTALLED>);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL(<YOUR QUERY WHEN DB VERSION CHANGES>);

}
```

Comment: Both functions added, when setting breakpoints they won't get triggered.

Comment: OnCreate gets called only when your app is installed for first Time. If you are using android studio and emulator, it won't uninstall your app, so it will be like update. For onUpgrade to tirgger,  you need to update( increase) your DATABASE_VERSION . Also add the constructor for your TestDatabase as updated in answer.

Comment: The constructor is in the code sample. And if I increase the DATABASE_VERSION DATABASE_VERSION the onUpgrade won't get triggered.

Comment: I'm developing on a real device, by uninstalling the app (adb uninstall ...) and reinstalling the app through Android Studio the onCreate won't get triggered as well.

Comment: can you make the constructor public ?

Comment: I've made the constructor public, but it didn't change anything.

Comment: That should have fixed your problem. Try uninstalling app direct from phone and install again with full clean-rebuild. For you reference, I am linking you to one of my previous answer which was thoroughly tested and guaranteed to work at that time.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24844514/database-in-android-studio/24844741#24844741

Comment: I've changed the DATABASE_NAME to a random name and the onCreate still isn't called, this is really weird behaviour. Is there something wrong with my device?

Comment: Do you actually make a call to database ? Try making a database call from your main activity and see if it triggers the onCreate and OnUpdate methods.

Comment: I've added a part of the MainActivity's onCreate()

Answer (score 0):

The database name constant doesn't usually include a '.db' extension, but I would be surprised if that was causing your error.

The getWriteableDatabase() call should be enough to trigger onCreate() or onUpgrade(), but perhaps it's being optimized out by the compiler because its result isn't used?

I'm going to test both of these options as soon as I can and edit with the results.

EDIT: Neither of those caused problems when I tested, are you sure getTestDatabase is being called somewhere? If not, then an instance isn't actually being created and that would explain why the code isn't running.

Comment: I've added the onCreate function from the MainActivity.

Answer (score 0):

As per my comments. I'm sure I was getting the same issue but I then added a breakpoint at `this.getWriteableDatabase();` and debugged. I then tried to step into code (came up with warnings and still does `Sources for Android API 26 Platform not found`) at

> ```
> public SQLiteDatabase getWritableDatabase() {
>     throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
> }
> ```

But has since worked. As such I'd suggest trying to do the same (perhaps try a clean and rebuild).

My code (below) is very much a copy of the code posted, except I made up table create code and I added some logging. The results of the logging very much confirm as per:-

```
10-20 21:12:48.879 24448-24448/? D/TESTDB: getTestDatabase invoked
10-20 21:12:48.879 24448-24448/? D/TESTDB: Calling Constructor from singleton
10-20 21:12:48.879 24448-24448/? D/TESTDB: Constructor Invoked
10-20 21:18:30.177 29719-29719/? D/TESTDB: getTestDatabase invoked
10-20 21:18:30.177 29719-29719/? D/TESTDB: Calling Constructor from singleton
10-20 21:18:30.177 29719-29719/? D/TESTDB: Constructor Invoked
10-20 21:18:44.181 29792-29792/? D/TESTDB: getTestDatabase invoked
10-20 21:18:44.181 29792-29792/? D/TESTDB: Calling Constructor from singleton
10-20 21:18:44.181 29792-29792/? D/TESTDB: Constructor Invoked
```

#### Note from here on the same code starts working and calls onCreate????

```
10-20 21:21:29.644 31659-31659/? D/TESTDB: getTestDatabase invoked
10-20 21:21:29.644 31659-31659/? D/TESTDB: Calling Constructor from singleton
10-20 21:21:29.644 31659-31659/? D/TESTDB: Constructor Invoked
10-20 21:21:29.666 31659-31659/? D/TESTDB: Oncreate Invoked
10-20 21:25:38.967 1069-1069/? D/TESTDB: getTestDatabase invoked
10-20 21:25:38.967 1069-1069/? D/TESTDB: Calling Constructor from singleton
10-20 21:25:38.967 1069-1069/? D/TESTDB: Constructor Invoked
10-20 21:26:06.221 1069-1069/? D/TESTDB: Oncreate Invoked
10-20 21:28:38.297 3941-3941/? D/TESTDB: getTestDatabase invoked
10-20 21:28:38.297 3941-3941/? D/TESTDB: Calling Constructor from singleton
10-20 21:28:38.297 3941-3941/? D/TESTDB: Constructor Invoked
10-20 21:28:44.602 4040-4040/? D/TESTDB: getTestDatabase invoked
10-20 21:28:44.602 4040-4040/? D/TESTDB: Calling Constructor from singleton
10-20 21:28:44.602 4040-4040/? D/TESTDB: Constructor Invoked
10-20 21:34:39.608 9786-9786/? D/TESTDB: getTestDatabase invoked
10-20 21:34:39.608 9786-9786/? D/TESTDB: Calling Constructor from singleton
10-20 21:34:39.608 9786-9786/? D/TESTDB: Constructor Invoked
10-20 21:36:48.139 10495-10495/? D/TESTDB: getTestDatabase invoked
10-20 21:36:48.139 10495-10495/? D/TESTDB: Calling Constructor from singleton
10-20 21:36:48.139 10495-10495/? D/TESTDB: Constructor Invoked
10-20 21:36:48.188 10495-10495/? D/TESTDB: Oncreate Invoked
```

Note! I didn't delete the database for a number of the runs above (the last run I did).

#### Changed version to 102 on onUpgrade called

```
10-20 21:41:49.007 15098-15098/? D/TESTDB: getTestDatabase invoked
10-20 21:41:49.007 15098-15098/? D/TESTDB: Calling Constructor from singleton
10-20 21:41:49.007 15098-15098/? D/TESTDB: Constructor Invoked
10-20 21:41:49.011 15098-15098/? D/TESTDB: onUpgrade invoked
```

The code I used (*please forgive the blatant plagiarism* :) ), oh an version is now 102 (used 101 originally) :-

```
public class TestDatabase extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 102;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "dbName.db";

    //Singleton
    private static TestDatabase testDatabase = null;

    public static TestDatabase getTestDatabase(Context context) {
        Log.d("TESTDB","getTestDatabase invoked");
        if (testDatabase == null) {
            Log.d("TESTDB", "Calling Constructor from singleton");
            testDatabase = new TestDatabase(context);
        }
        return testDatabase;
    }

    private TestDatabase(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        Log.d("TESTDB","Constructor Invoked");
        this.getWritableDatabase();
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        Log.d("TESTDB","Oncreate Invoked");
        String tblcrt = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS testtable (" +
                "_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
                "COL1 TEXT" +
                ")";
        db.execSQL(tblcrt);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {
        Log.d("TESTDB","onUpgrade invoked");
    }
}
```

along with :-

```
......
TestDatabase testdb;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    setViewIDs();
    setDBViewerButton(mButton1); // setup Button 1 for DBViewer

    testdb = TestDatabase.getTestDatabase(this);
    .....
}
```

Comment: I've tested the code, and a very weird thing happens. When running my code on an emulator the onCreate and onUpdate are triggered. When running the code on a real device the onCreate and onUpdate won't get triggered.

Comment: @GilianJoosen try changing `public static TestDatabase getTestDatabase(.....` to `static synchronized TestDatabase getTestDatabase(.....`